# How to get URL specific details and Request Type(GET, POST, PUT) from ServletRequestEvent?

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-listeners

I am implementing [`ServletRequestListener`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/apidocs/jakarta/servlet/servletrequestlistener) and overriding its methods `requestInitialized` and `requestDestroyed`.

When `requestDestroyed` is called, I want to know details like whether the request is a GET/POST request and the parameters sent along with it. What should be the approach?

```
public void requestDestroyed(ServletRequestEvent event) {
    ServletRequest s = event.getServletRequest();
    //use this to get those details
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [`ServletRequestEvent`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/apidocs/jakarta/servlet/ServletRequestEvent.html) passed to the [`ServletRequestListener`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/apidocs/jakarta/servlet/servletrequestlistener) you implemented, call [`getServletRequest`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/apidocs/jakarta/servlet/servletrequestevent#getServletRequest()) to get a [`ServletRequest`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/apidocs/jakarta/servlet/ServletRequest.html) object. Then cast to the subinterface, [`HttpServletRequest`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/apidocs/jakarta/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html).

From there you can interrogate for parts of the URL. See [this post](https://agiletribe.wordpress.com/2016/02/23/httpservletrequest-path-decoding/) for a handy diagram of the various parts of a URL mapped to various methods on that class.

```
public void requestDestroyed(ServletRequestEvent event) {
    ServletRequest s = event.getServletRequest();
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) s;  // Cast to subinterface.

    String method = request.getMethod();
    Map<String,String[]> parameters = request.getParameterMap();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works for the problem I was trying to solve. :)